real quasi-convex functions
A function $f:I\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $I$ inteval is said quasi-convex if $\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x\in I:f(x)\le \alpha\}$ is a interval.
Equivalently $f(tx+(1-t)y)\le \max\{f(x),f(y)\}$ for all $x,y\in I$ and $t\in [0,1]$.
I have found (without proof) this theorem

If f is quasi-convex on interval I, then either $f$ is monotone or there is $t\in\operatorname{int}(I)$
such that $f$ is decreasing on (−∞,] ∩  and increasing on  ∩ [, ∞)

How can I prove it?

My idea is consider $t=sup\{x\in I: f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,x]\cap I\}$.
Ps. the point $t$ can belong to only one of interval $(−∞,) ∩ $ and  $ ∩ (, ∞).$

Notice first that any monotone function $f$ over the interval $I$ is both quasi-convex and quasi-concave.
Now, suppose $f$ is quasi-convex and  non-monotone.
If for no $t\in \operatorname{int}(I)$ is $f$ monotone non-increasing in $I\cap(-\infty,t)$ and $f$ monotone non-decreasing in $I\cap(t,\infty)$, then  convince yourself that there are points $t_1<t_2<t_3$ in $\operatorname{int}(I)$ such that
$$f(t_1)<f(t_2),\quad f(t_2)>f(t_3)$$
Then $t_2=\lambda t_1+(1-\lambda)t_3$ for some $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and so,
$$\max(f(x_1),f(x_3)<f(\lambda t_1+(1-\lambda)t_2)$$
in contradiction to the assumption that $f$ is quasi-convex.
